# How to properly scale camera feed and segmentation in Spark AR

Tags: facebook, instagram, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am working on a Spark AR lens where I need the camera feed of the user to be scaled down to about half the normal size. I have figured out how to scale the camera texture and the segmentation texture to fit my need.

The issue I'm having now is that the pixels around the edge of the newly updated scale get stretched to the size of the parent canvas as you can see in this image:

[image]

My patches can be seen here:

[image]

How can I prevent this pixel stretching from showing outside of the red square in image 1?

Answer (score 0):

I simple solution would be to apply the camera texture to a rect, and scale the rect down instead. Another way to do this would be to create a custom shader, but that's more complicated.

Here's a working example that uses no patches and no code:

[image]